# Linear layout in frame refuses to go landscape

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, frames

I am placing my application in landscape mode in my `manifest`:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".VerticalSlideshow"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_prime" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

I have a `FrameLayout` containing a vertical `ScrollView` in the background which is humming along fine and a `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` some buttons in the foreground. Everything works fine except the foreground image/buttons will not go into landscape mode using the emulator. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ddffff" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_scrollview_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdge="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/horiztonal_outer_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/moving"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/clear"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/truck1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0.12"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/carfs"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/policef"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/taxif"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:background="@drawable/amulancef"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The XML preview in Eclipse looks fine. Should I test on a real phone? Ultimately, how can I force this linearview into landscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put android:screenOrientation="landscape" in your activity tag instead of application tag in your manifest file